# How can I find a fossilized spine to donate to the Island Field office on Ginger Island?

Tags: stardew-valley

Here's the last hint I get:

> "You know, there's some great fishing on this island. From what I know, many of the fish enjoy nibbling on ancient bones..."

I haven't had much luck fishing near the dig site. Also, by "nibbling on ancient bones", I originally thought that bone fragments can be used as bait, but it doesn't seem possible.

Is there a specific location to fish from, or rod to fish with, at the dig site to increase my chances of finding the fossilized spine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like the Iridium Rod should do the trick for catching the spine out of the river according to [this video](https://youtu.be/jkh13BlVOMA?t=41).  Make sure you are fishing from the river that in the dig site, and not the small one you cross to enter the dig site:

[image: river]

Alternatively, you can also find the spine from Artifact Spots on the south beach, but fishing is probably quicker.

Like the video illustrates, a [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/StardewValley/comments/kieuh6/how_to_get_this_fossil/) says the spine is caught similar to trash or also in a treasure chest:

> Spine: fishing in the river at the digging site (EDIT: can be fished up in treasure OR in like trash/algae)